# What are latent representations?

Tags: deep-learning, representation, graph-neural-network

I am reading some research papers about *graph convolutional neural networks* and I have seen the term "latent representations" used a lot. For instance, "*the model was able to learn latent representations of the nodes of the graph*".

What does the word "latent" means here? Is it the same as latent features?

Answer (score 2):

The latent representation is the simplified model of your input data, for example, created by a neural network.

Considering an autoencoder, the central layer of this network (after training) will contain a simplified representation of the input data (i.e. summary of key features), which can be used to reconstruct the output.

If we take a dictionary definition of Latent: *present and capable of emerging or developing but not now visible, obvious, active, or symptomatic*, we can see how this describes the somewhat non-existence of the state, rather instead only a latent representation of the input data.

[This image](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781789138900/5/ch05lvl1sec57/latent-representation) is a nice description. The latent representation is key features of the input data (here: the ears, nose, eyes of the animals.)

[image]

So yes, the latent representation is the sum of the latent features.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you should reconsider the point _i.e. " created by your neural network"_. It can be without a Neural Network.